# How to get arguments in constructor class in IntelliJ?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm

When I create an extension for PhpStorm. This extension auto-generates the code for the unit test. I want to move the use and get arguments constructor arguments in the parent class.

[image]

1. How to move using in `CleanTableCronJob` class to the `CleanTableCronJobTest` class?
2. How to get constructor arguments in `CleanTableCronJob`?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include your code in your question instead of using a picture.

Comment: Hi @M-Chen-3 I updated the code in this link:
https://gist.github.com/dylanngo95/ca256c9b06cc515c5cc43646ae32e8d1
Thanks :))